# How to run action one by one?

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-js

Hi i wanna make flip card animation in Cocos2d-js and flipX3d(duration) cause fail of application here is my code.

```
var MenuLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
spriteBG:null,

ctor:function () {
    this._super();
    this.init();
},
init:function() {

    var size = cc.winSize;

    var closeItem = new cc.MenuItemImage(
        res.CloseNormal_png,
        res.CloseSelected_png,
        function () {
            cc.log("Close is clicked!");
        }, this);
    closeItem.attr({
        x: size.width - 20,
        y: 20,
        anchorX: 0.5,
        anchorY: 0.5
    });

    var menu = new cc.Menu(closeItem);
    menu.x = 0;
    menu.y = 0;
    this.addChild(menu, 1);

    this.spriteBG = new cc.Sprite(res.MenuBG);

    this.spriteBG.attr({
        x: size.width / 2,
        y: size.height / 2,
        scale: 1.5
    });
    this.addChild(this.spriteBG, 0);

    this.pomoc = new cc.Sprite(res.Card_Back);
    this.pomoc.setPosition(size.width/3, size.height/3);
    this.addChild(this.pomoc, 2, 1);

    this.pomoc1 = new cc.Sprite(res.Card_Back);
    this.pomoc1.setPosition(size.width/3, size.height/3);
    this.pomoc1.runAction(cc.scaleTo(0, 0, 1));
    this.addChild(this.pomoc1, 2, 1);
    cc.FlipX3D

    var startButton = new cc.MenuItemSprite( 
            new cc.Sprite(res.Start_1),
            new cc.Sprite(res.Start_2),
            function(){


                cc.log("==start clicked");
                var pop = cc.scaleTo(0.5, 0, 1);
                var pop1 = cc.scaleTo(0.5, 1, 1);
                var seq = new cc.Sequence(this.pomoc.runAction(pop),this.pomoc1.runAction(pop1));
            },this
    );
    var Start = new cc.Menu(startButton);
    Start.setPosition(size.width/2, size.height/2)
    this.addChild(Start);

}
});



var MenuScene = cc.Scene.extend({
onEnter:function () {
    this._super();
    var layer = new MenuLayer();
    this.addChild(layer);
}
});
```

Problem is pop and pop1 are started at once i need to do pop and then pop1. Sequance should help but it ignores it and start at the same time. Thanks for help.

even if i split it into functions and then call in sequance it start at the same time.

```
var MenuLayer = cc.Layer.extend({
spriteBG:null,

ctor:function () {
    this._super();
    this.init();
},
init:function() {

    var size = cc.winSize;

    var closeItem = new cc.MenuItemImage(
        res.CloseNormal_png,
        res.CloseSelected_png,
        function () {
            cc.log("Close is clicked!");
        }, this);
    closeItem.attr({
        x: size.width - 20,
        y: 20,
        anchorX: 0.5,
        anchorY: 0.5
    });

    var menu = new cc.Menu(closeItem);
    menu.x = 0;
    menu.y = 0;
    this.addChild(menu, 1);

    this.spriteBG = new cc.Sprite(res.MenuBG);

    this.spriteBG.attr({
        x: size.width / 2,
        y: size.height / 2,
        scale: 1.5
    });
    this.addChild(this.spriteBG, 0);

    this.pomoc = new cc.Sprite(res.Card_Back);
    this.pomoc.setPosition(size.width/3, size.height/3);
    this.addChild(this.pomoc, 2, 1);

    this.pomoc1 = new cc.Sprite(res.Card_Back);
    this.pomoc1.setPosition(size.width/3+10, size.height/3+10);
    this.pomoc1.runAction(cc.scaleTo(0, 0, 1));
    this.addChild(this.pomoc1, 2, 1);

    var startButton = new cc.MenuItemSprite( 
            new cc.Sprite(res.Start_1),
            new cc.Sprite(res.Start_2),
            function(){


                cc.log("==start clicked");
                cc.Sequence.create(this.pom1(),this.pom2());
            },this
    );
    var Start = new cc.Menu(startButton);
    Start.setPosition(size.width/2, size.height/2)
    this.addChild(Start);

},
pom1: function(){
    this.pomoc.runAction(cc.scaleTo(0.5, 0, 1));
},
pom2:function(){
    this.pomoc1.runAction(cc.scaleTo(1, 1, 1));
}
});



var MenuScene = cc.Scene.extend({
onEnter:function () {
    this._super();
    var layer = new MenuLayer();
    this.addChild(layer);
}
});
```

Comment: cc.Sequence(pop, pop1) ... you run the sequence, not the actions within it

Comment: yes i understand but i need to start pop action with pomoc (this.pomoc.runAction(pop)) and then start action pop1 with pomoc1 (this.pomoc1.runAction(pop1)).

    var act1 = this.pomoc.runAction(pop)
    var act2 = this.pomoc1.runAction(pop1)
    will start both action at the same time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, when you want to run actions on different objects within one same sequence, you need to use `callFunc`. But you should also keep in mind that (as far as I know) `callFunc` doesn't have a way of telling the `Sequence` that's wrapping it when it ends, so you should put a `Delay` there.

It's also a bit wierd how you are using this.. When are the actions supposed to run? Defining `seq` should only create the sequence. but not execute it.

Keeping your style of doing things, you should replace this:

```
var seq = new cc.Sequence(this.pomoc.runAction(pop),this.pomoc1.runAction(pop1));
```

With this:

```
var seq = cc.sequence(
    cc.callFunc(function(){that.pomoc.runAction(pop);}),
    cc.delay(1),
    cc.callFunc(function(){that.pomoc1.runAction(pop1);})
);
```

But if it were me, I'd just do this (wherever you actually want the sequence to be executed):

```
this.pomoc.runAction(
    cc.sequence(
        pop,
        cc.callFunc(function(){that.pomoc1.runAction(pop1);})
    )
);
```

This should run `pop` on `this.pomoc`, and *when that ends* execute the `callFunc`. IMHO that's your best option.

---

Note that, within the `callFunc`, `this` won't have the meaning you expect, so you should define `var that = this;`, right before your `var size = cc.winSize;` would be a good place.

PS: note that in v3.x you don't need to use `new` and `.create()` on your actions if you use the versions of the methods that start with lowercase, ie: `cc.sequence` equals  `new cc.Sequence.create`.

Quick warning though: if you wish to use an action that you've defined somewhere (ie `pop`) on two objects at the same time, you'll need to add a `.clone()` at each place where you call it (ie: `that.pomoc.runAction(pop.clone());`).

Comment: Thanks a lot im newbie in cocos and javascript and whole explanation rly helped and it works great.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.pomoc.runAction(cc.Sequence.create(pop, cc.CallFunc.create(startPop1, this)));

function startPop1(obj) {
   this.pomoc1.runAction(pop1);
}
```

or:

```
this.pomoc.runAction(pop);
this.pomoc1.runAction(cc.Sequence.create(cc.DelayTime.create(popActionDuration), pop1));
```

Comment: i tried this and it runs both  pop and pop1 at the same time. Anyway thanks